# Angular6 long waiting to change

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-changedetection

I've updated my Angular app to Angular6.

I noticed that my components which are for example displaying data from Observable using pipes are stuck. I mean that they are working, but I have to wait a very long time to auto-update this component.

For example I have store with auth data with flag `isLogged`. According to this flag some component is changing `<button>` content from *Sign in* to *Sign out* - I think you get the idea.

In previous Angular version (5.x) when I signed in, immediately my button was updated and content was *Sign out*

Currently I have to wait a long time to this button change. There is also another strange behavior - When I clicked on this button, he immediately realized that he has to update, and *Sign out* appears.

This was only one example, but in my app there are a lot of such components.

Comment: For some reason, you're probably either skipping a change detection cycle and so your UI is updated at the next one (every time you click, there's a new CD running, that's why it might be updated when you click on a button). OR, you're just not respecting the immutability somewhere and if you've set your component to onPush... It's normal.

Comment: So do you have any hint how to not skipping a cd cycle?

Comment: Is the component where you display your button set to onpsuh (change detection strategy) ?

Comment: Are you injecting ChangeDetectorRef?

Comment: Are you running some code outside of NgZone?

Comment: 1. no, I ddn't set any cd strategy

Comment: 2. No injecting CD ref

Comment: 3. hmm I don't know

Comment: Are you sure to respect immutability? Do you have ngrx store freeze?

Comment: No, I haven't - should I have this?

Comment: Yes when working with NGRX, immutability must be guaranteed. And it's not up to ngrx to make sure of that, it's up to the developer. Hopefully, there's a very handy package, ngrx store freeze. It'll help you make sure that you do not mutate your state. Make a ternary to only use it in dev mode because it might hurt perfs (but it's so helpful while developing)

Comment: I've made an example in my ngrx starter, you can take a look here https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter/blob/master/src/app/shared/states/root.reducer.ts#L28

Comment: I checked that my ngrx store is correctly set, in immutable way ;) 
Components still have problems with refreshing on time

Comment: Can you make a repro on stackblitz?

Comment: It will be very hard... Now I'm trying to force CD, to check if this will help, but probably this will be bad approach anyway

Comment: Probably yeah. If you manage to isolate the problem and make a repro I might take a look. Otherwise... Good luck I hope you'll find from where it comes from!